# How many Q-Fieldhomomorphisms from the algebraic numbers to the complex numbers are there?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I guess there is only one from the rational numbers to the complex numbers,
since they form the prime-field.

However I have no idea, how to approach
the question of how many homomorphisms from the algebraic closure of the rational numbers to the complex numbers there are, that keep the rational numbers fixed.

If someone has an idea on how to approach this question, I'd be really curious.
Thank you and have a good day!

Comment: Why do you need to know how many such field homomorphisms are?

Comment: Possibly related (probably relevant?) is [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/285567/13130).

Answer (score 0):

They are infinitely many.  A Zorn lemma argument shows that for any algebraic extension $L/\mathbb{Q}$, you can extend any $\mathbb{Q}$-morphism $L\to\mathbb{C}$ to a  $\mathbb{Q}$-morphism $L\to\mathbb{C}$

Now for any integer $n$, pick an extension of degree $n$, say $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$. You have $n$ morphisms $L\to\mathbb{C}$,  extending to morphisms $\mathbb{Q}$-morphism $\mathbb{Q}$-morphism $L\to\mathbb{C}$ , necessarily distinct, since their restrictions to $L$ are.

Hence, for all $n$, $\vert Hom_\mathbb{Q}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}},\mathbb{C})\vert\geq n$, QED.